# Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "conversation-detail"

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I'm building an rest api in django rest but I'm getting this and I don't know how to solve it.

"ImproperlyConfigured at /conversation/1/
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "conversation-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field. "

models.py

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
storeId       = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
operatorId    = models.ForeignKey(Operator, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='operatorId')
clientId      = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
operatorGroup = models.ForeignKey(Operator, to_field='group', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='operatorGroup')
```

views.py

```
class ConversationApiView(APIView):

def get(self, request, id, *args, **kwargs):
    conversations = Conversation.objects.filter(id=id)
    serializer = ConversationSerializer(conversations, context={'request': request}, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

serializers.py

```
class ConversationSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Conversation
    fields = ('__all__')
```

ursl.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('conversation/<int:id>/', ConversationApiView.as_view()),
path('chat/<int:id>/', ChatApiView.as_view()),
```

]

root urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
path('', include('api.urls')),
```

]

THANK YOU in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Inside view, you should use `ModelViewSet` instead of `APIView`. I saw you are using generic view which is not developed for HyperlinkedModelSerializer. So, Your code should be something like this:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets



class ConversationApiView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

def get(self, request, id, *args, **kwargs):
    conversations = Conversation.objects.filter(id=id)
    serializer = ConversationSerializer(conversations, context={'request': request}, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And url.py should be like this:

```
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('conversation', ConversationApiView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

After that Every CRUD Url auto generate like `localhost:8000/conversation/`,